# How to read a file at a specific offset position using ReadFile() Windows API (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Following C# snippet executes sequential reads of pages in a binary files.

For certain delicate reasons - ***using ReadFile() Windows System API is a must.***

```
for (iReadCounter = 0; iReadCounter < iReadCountLimit; iReadCounter++)
{
    readsize = DefineConstants.READ_BUF_SIZE;
    bool bResult = ReadFile(fhnd, readbuffer, (uint)readsize, out readresult, ref _overlapped);
    .
    .
}
```

Is there a way by which **ReadFile()** can be directed to read at a specific file offset/position of choice?

Thanks.

/H

Comment: The .NET libraries are all effectively wrappers around the Windows API, so it's a little redundant to say you need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `lpOverlapped` parameter of `ReadFile()` to a reference to an `_overlapped` variable. So you need to use the `_overlapped.Offset` and `_overlapped.OffsetHigh` fields to specify the desired file offset to read from.

Per the [`ReadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) documentation:

> `[in, out, optional] lpOverlapped`
>
> A pointer to an `OVERLAPPED` structure is required if the `hFile` parameter was opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, otherwise it can be NULL.
>
> If `hFile` is opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, the `lpOverlapped` parameter must point to a valid and unique `OVERLAPPED` structure, otherwise the function can incorrectly report that the read operation is complete.
>
> **For an `hFile` that supports byte offsets, if you use this parameter you must specify a byte offset at which to start reading from the file or device. This offset is specified by setting the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members of the `OVERLAPPED` structure.** For an `hFile` that does not support byte offsets, `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` are ignored.
>
> For more information about different combinations of `lpOverlapped` and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, see the Remarks section and the Synchronization and File Position section.

And the "Synchronization and File Position" section says:

> If `hFile` is opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, it is an asynchronous file handle; otherwise it is synchronous. The rules for using the `OVERLAPPED` structure are slightly different for each, as previously noted.
>
> ...
>
> Considerations for working with asynchronous file handles:
>
> - ...
> - The lpOverlapped parameter must not be NULL and should be used with the following facts in mind:
>
>   - Although the event specified in the OVERLAPPED structure is set and reset automatically by the system, **the offset that is specified in the OVERLAPPED structure is not automatically updated**.
>   - ...
>   - Because **the read operation starts at the offset that is specified in the `OVERLAPPED` structure**, and `ReadFile` may return before the system-level read operation is complete (read pending), neither the offset nor any other part of the structure should be modified, freed, or reused by the application until the event is signaled (that is, the read completes).
>   - ...
>
> Considerations for working with synchronous file handles:
>
> - ...
> - **If `lpOverlapped` is not NULL, the read operation starts at the offset that is specified in the `OVERLAPPED` structure and `ReadFile` does not return until the read operation is complete. The system updates the `OVERLAPPED` offset before `ReadFile` returns.**
> - ...

Had you been setting the `lpOverlapped` parameter to `null` instead, then you would have to use [`SetFilePointer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) or [`SetFilePointerEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) to specify the desired offset:

> Considerations for working with synchronous file handles:
>
> - **If `lpOverlapped` is NULL, the read operation starts at the current file position** and `ReadFile` does not return until the operation is complete, and the system updates the file pointer before `ReadFile` returns.
> - ...

Answer (score 1):

If the file actually supports reading at a specific position (not a given), you should be able to use the Offset and OffsetHigh members of the OVERLAPPED parameter to specify the read position.

This should work even if the file was not opened for overlapped I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do this with `SetFilePointer` or `SetFilePointerEx`. It allows you to set where the file handle is pointing at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer

Comment: This is true only when the `lpOverlapped` parameter of `ReadFile()` is NULL, which is not the case in the code provided by the OP.